# Foreign Keys causing error when trying to insert values

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-8.0

I'm a student working on an assignment for school. The assignment is to create a stored procedure that counts the number of employees, regions, etc in other tables. I created all the tables and added the foreign keys like I was instructed. It works great. However, whenever I copy and past the code that the instructor gave us that inserts data into the table, I get this error many times:

"Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

```
  empid INT PRIMARY KEY,
  fname VARCHAR(15),
  hiredate datetime,
  deptid INT
  );
 
  CREATE TABLE dept (
   deptid INT PRIMARY KEY,
   deptname VARCHAR(20),
   locid INT
    );
   
  CREATE TABLE location(
  locid INT PRIMARY KEY,
    locname VARCHAR(20),
    state VARCHAR(2),
    regionid INT
    );

 CREATE TABLE region (
  regionid INT PRIMARY KEY,
   regname VARCHAR(4)
   );
CREATE TABLE salary (
empid INT PRIMARY KEY,
  paygrade VARCHAR(2),
amount DECIMAL (10,2),
  lupdate timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
FOREIGN KEY (empid) REFERENCES emp(empid)
);

CREATE TABLE sales (
invoiceid INT PRIMARY KEY,
  deptid INT,
  saesamt DECIMAL (10,2),
  salesdate DATETIME,
  FOREIGN KEY (deptid) REFERENCES dept(deptid)
);



ALTER TABLE emp
ADD FOREIGN KEY (deptid) REFERENCES dept(deptid);

ALTER TABLE dept
ADD FOREIGN KEY (locid) REFERENCES location(locid);

ALTER TABLE location
ADD FOREIGN KEY (regionid) REFERENCES region(regionid);

ALTER TABLE emp COMMENT 'this is the employee table';

ALTER TABLE dept COMMENT 'This is the dept table';


ALTER TABLE location COMMENT 'Shows location name and state by region';

ALTER TABLE emp
MODIFY COLUMN hiredate datetime COMMENT 'Employee date of hire';
```

Like I said, the code above works fine, no issues. However, whenever I try to insert values into the tables by copying and pasting the following code into db-fiddle (which we were given permission to do),
I get the error mentioned above.

```
#  REGION INSERTS

insert into region values (1, 'NW');
insert into region values (2, 'W');
insert into region values (3, 'SW');
insert into region values (4, 'MW');
insert into region values (5, 'NE');
insert into region values (6, 'E');
insert into region values (7, 'SE');


# LOCATION INSERTS

insert into location values (1, 'Seattle','WA', 1);
insert into location values (2, 'Portland','OR', 1);
insert into location values (3, 'Boise','ID', 1);
insert into location values (4, 'San Francisco','CA', 2);
insert into location values (5, 'Sacramento','CA', 2);
insert into location values (6, 'Fremont','CA', 2);
insert into location values (7, 'Oceanside','CA', 2);
insert into location values (8, 'Monterrey','CA', 2);
insert into location values (9, 'Los Angeles','CA', 2);
insert into location values (10, 'San Diego','CA', 2);
insert into location values (11, 'Salt Lake City','UT', 2);
insert into location values (12, 'St. George','UT', 2);
insert into location values (13, 'Provo','UT', 2);
insert into location values (14, 'Ogden','UT', 2);
insert into location values (15, 'Logan','UT', 2);
insert into location values (16, 'Las Vegas','NV', 2);
insert into location values (17, 'Reno','NV', 2);
insert into location values (18, 'Carson City','NV', 2);
insert into location values (19, 'Boulder City','NV', 2);
insert into location values (20, 'Santa Fe','NM', 3);
insert into location values (21, 'Las Cruces','NM', 3);
insert into location values (22, 'Roswell','NM', 3);
insert into location values (23, 'Taos','NM', 3);
insert into location values (24, 'Phoenix','AZ', 3);
insert into location values (25, 'Tucson','AZ', 3);
insert into location values (26, 'Tempe','AZ', 3);
insert into location values (27, 'Scottsdale','AZ', 3);
insert into location values (28, 'Flagstaff','AZ', 3);


#  SALARY INSERTS
insert into salary values (1, 'T5', 98000.00, '2018-01-11');
insert into salary values (2, 'A1', 208000.00, '2018-01-11');
insert into salary values (3, 'A1', 255000.00, '2018-01-11');
insert into salary values (4, 'A1', 247000.00, '2018-01-11');
insert into salary values (5, 'A1', 245000.00, '2018-01-11');
insert into salary values (6, 'A1', 289000.00, '2018-01-11');


# SALES INSERTS

insert into sales values (101, 2, 2111.02, '20160102');
insert into sales values (102, 2, 421.00, '20160202');
insert into sales values (103, 2, 675.00, '20160202');
insert into sales values (104, 2, 4355.00, '20160302');
insert into sales values (105, 2, 975.00, '20160304');
insert into sales values (106, 2, 1021.00, '20160402');
insert into sales values (107, 2, 2106.00, '20160425');
insert into sales values (108, 2, 2799.81, '20160501');
insert into sales values (109, 2, 4335.75, '20160502');
insert into sales values (110, 2, 12006.00, '20160521');
insert into sales values (111, 2, 5220.00, '20160602');
insert into sales values (112, 2, 7198.02, '20160618');
insert into sales values (113, 2, 4795.00, '20160625');
insert into sales values (114, 2, 5341.00, '20160706');
insert into sales values (115, 2, 5795.00, '20160718');
insert into sales values (116, 2, 6400.00, '20160725');
insert into sales values (117, 2, 14795.00, '20160812');
insert into sales values (118, 2, 43395.00, '20160825');
insert into sales values (119, 2, 47595.00, '20160914');
insert into sales values (120, 2, 46795.00, '20160930');
insert into sales values (121, 2, 6223.00, '20161010');
insert into sales values (122, 2, 7702.00, '20161012');
insert into sales values (123, 2, 11292.00, '20161107');
insert into sales values (124, 2, 33211.00, '20161126');
insert into sales values (125, 2, 16430.00, '20161206');
insert into sales values (126, 2, 87010.00, '20161221');
insert into sales values (127, 2, 2111.02, '20170102');
insert into sales values (128, 2, 421.00, '20170202');
insert into sales values (129, 2, 675.00, '20170202');
insert into sales values (130, 2, 4355.00, '20170302');
insert into sales values (131, 2, 975.00, '20170304');
insert into sales values (132, 2, 1021.00, '20170402');
insert into sales values (133, 2, 2106.00, '20170425');
insert into sales values (134, 2, 2799.81, '20170501');
insert into sales values (135, 2, 4335.75, '20170502');
insert into sales values (136, 2, 12006.00, '20170521');
insert into sales values (137, 2, 5220.00, '20170602');
insert into sales values (138, 2, 7198.02, '20170618');
insert into sales values (139, 2, 4795.00, '20170625');
insert into sales values (140, 2, 5341.00, '20170706');
insert into sales values (141, 2, 7004.00, '20170718');
insert into sales values (142, 2, 14991.00, '20170725');
insert into sales values (143, 2, 34076.00, '20170812');
insert into sales values (144, 2, 47950.00, '20170825');
insert into sales values (145, 2, 40795.00, '20170914');
insert into sales values (146, 2, 41795.00, '20170930');
insert into sales values (147, 2, 47295.00, '20171010');
insert into sales values (148, 2, 47395.00, '20171012');
insert into sales values (149, 2, 41795.00, '20171107');
insert into sales values (150, 2, 47895.00, '20161126');
insert into sales values (151, 2, 87666.00, '20161206');
insert into sales values (152, 2, 9401.00, '20161221');

# DEPT INSERTS 

insert into dept values (1, 'Engineering', 3);
insert into dept values (2, 'Sales', 1);
insert into dept values (3, 'Marketing', 1);
insert into dept values (4, 'Shipping', 3);
insert into dept values (5, 'Sales Support', 2);
insert into dept values (6, 'Executive', 1);
insert into dept values (7, 'Accounting', 3);
insert into dept values (8, 'Receiving', 3);
insert into dept values (9, 'Mfg', 3);
insert into dept values (10, 'People', 3);
insert into dept values (11, 'IT', 2);

#  EMP INSERTS

insert into emp values (1, 'Wagner','Richard', '20150105', 3);
insert into emp values (2, 'Walton','Mark', '20150105', 1);
insert into emp values (3, 'West','Paul', '20150105', 1);
insert into emp values (4, 'Baxter','Thomas', '20150105', 1);
insert into emp values (5, 'Martin','Philip', '20150105', 1);
insert into emp values (6, 'Reynolds','Jason', '20150105', 1);
```

Comment: This is a faq. Google site:stackoverflow.com with your error less strings specific to your code. When you have a non-duplicate code question [mre] is needed but that's not minimal. Isolate the 1st bad subexpression. [ask] [help] PS A FK constraint says certain values must appear elsewhere. Yours don't.

Comment: You can't insert `salary` rows (with an FK to `emp`) before the `emp` rows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the sequence in which you are inserting into the tables. Your tables have foreign keys: before you can insert a row in a child table, you need to create it in the parent table first.

Your DDL shows the following constraints:

- regions need to be created before locations
- departments must be created before employees and sales
- salaries require employees

Here is a possible sequence for the inserts:

```
region
location
dept
sales
emp
salary
```